# How to sign a message with DKIM signature using Symfony Mailer component?

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

It seems that [SwiftMailer is being replaced by new Symfony mailer component](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/971). The last comment by SwiftMailer maintainer:

> .... the namespaced version of Swiftmailer is now available... as Symfony Mailer.

Before migrating to the new component, I would like to know if it supports DKIM signing of messages? I don't see it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: An issue has been created here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/36014

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code example how you can add DKIM signer.

```
$private_key = "your private key"; 
$domain = "your domain";
$selector = "Your domain selector";
$signer = new DkimSigner($private_key , $domain , $selector );
$options = array();
$signedEmail = $signer->sign($email, $options);
$email = $signedEmail;
////// last send email 
$mailer->send($email);
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

1. The line you mentioned doesn't mean that they are going to migrate and stop supporting swiftmailer. so you may  want to wait a bit more before deciding to migrate.
2. Glancing at Symfony Mailer's code repository I didn't found any relative lines to DKIM‌ signing implementation. It seems to have a lack of feature. Maybe in order to cleaning up the code or lack of resources.
3. DKIM signing could be done on the side of SMTP server. Then it will sign any outgoing email with its private key and include the signature on the email message header which later could be used by the receiver mail server to authorize the sender. You may be able to handle it there.

Comment: It is one of the features of SwiftMailer: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Signers/DKIMSigner.php

Comment: OK, seems that they implement this feature to be used against those servers which has not enabled it. thank you for your comment @Karolis